# reading a ptd/zgy file

Tags: ocean, petrel

Is there a way to read the ptd or zgy file outside of Petrel?  I have an application that would like to read the 3d seismic data that petrel holds in these formats without opening petrel to export the data into ASCII or something else.  Obviously its a better user experience to just read it from my own application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **zgy** access C++ library deployed with Petrel. It's named Slb.Salmon.ZgyPublic.zip and located in the Petrel root folder. The archive contains binaries (native DLLs), C++ header files and documentation.

As for **ptd**, it is an extension of a folder name which contains files in many formats (binary, XML etc.), belonging to one project. The project's main file has **pet** extension, it is stored in binary format. There is no documentation on the format, it may change without notice, so you are not supposed to read those files directly.

Comment: Documentation just lists classes but I was wondering if there was more out there?

Comment: That documentation is what we have at the moment. There is one short code sample in the archive as well. Please let us know if you have more specific questions.